# How to prevent line break inside a column of a table using enumerate?

Tags: tables, enumerate

The code below is a simplified version of the code I'm making. The problem is that inside the third column, before the beggining of enumerate, the code is breaking a line. How to prevent that this happens? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[p]
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{3cm}p{4cm}}

\hline 
\footnotesize Example & \footnotesize Example & \footnotesize Example \\
\hline 
\footnotesize Example & \footnotesize Example & \footnotesize 
\begin{enumerate} 
    \item Example.
    \item Example.
\end{enumerate}\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really breaking a line, so much as adding vertical space above the list. Minor technical detail, but it's worth understanding

Comment: @Au101 - Great minds think alike -- see my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Au101 in his comment, you can't prevent it, but you can annihilate it. I suggest using `enumitem` to define enumerate environments adapted to tables. In addition, you should use `booktabs` to have table rules with some vertical padding (usually, LaTeX produces very tight tables):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate, 1]{label=\arabic*., wide, nosep, before=\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[p] \footnotesize \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{3cm}p{4cm}}
  \hline
  Example & Example & Example \\
  \hline
  Example & Example &
  \begin{tabenumerate}%
    \item Example.
    \item Example.
  \end{tabenumerate} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much a matter of line breaks being inserted as it is of LaTeX inserting vertical space above (and below) the `enumerate` environment. I suggest you (a) load the package `enumitem` and pass the option `nosep` to the `enumerate` environment and (b) remove the remaining vertical whitespace with a suitable `\vspace` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{rotating,enumitem,array}
\newcolumntype{f}[1]{>{\footnotesize}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{f{2.5cm}f{3cm}f{4cm}}
\hline 
Example & Example & Example \\
\hline 
Example & Example &  
\vspace*{-0.58\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep] % <-- note the "nosep" option
    \item Example.
    \item Example.
\end{enumerate}\\[-2.2ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good explanation and good answer =)